# Ability to add a separator/newline in organize imports preferences (Scala-IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, scala-ide

How to configure eclipse organize imports to separate imports from different groups by new lines.

For example

If imports are coming from

```
java.*
com.*
```

Then they should be organized as

```
java.*

com.*
```

I have seen one related bug report , not sure if it was ever worked.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10961

Answer (score 4):

> "How to configure eclipse organize imports to separate imports from different groups by new lines."

Go:

- [**Window**] → [**Preferences**] → [**Java**] → [**Code Style**] → [**Formatter**]
- At the top of the diaolog, you should see the "Active Profile" combo box. Select the <kbd>Edit...</kbd>.
- Go to [**Blank Lines**] tab, and edit [**Between Import Groups**]. Set it to 1 if you want one space

[image]

[image]